# React Jest Enzyme change Material UI Checkbox

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I would like to test checkboxes made with Material UI in React with Jest/Enzyme.

I can easily test some text but I can't find the checkboxes and change the status.

Checkbox:

```
  <FormControlLabel
            control={
              <Checkbox
                data-testid={x.label}
                ...
```

The test:

```
describe("Jobs Filtering2", () => {
  it("Set data", () => {
 
    const TestComp = () => {

      // Context imports
      const {
      ...
      } = useContext(JobsContext);

      useEffect(() => {
       ...
      }, []);
    
      return <Jobs />;
    };

    const wrapper = mount(
      // User data
      <UserContext.Provider value={{ userData: userData }}>
        <JobsContextProvider>
          <TestComp />
        </JobsContextProvider>
      </UserContext.Provider>
    );

    // Find in UI
    // Read the total jobs
    expect(wrapper.find(`.jobs-header__sub`).text()).toEqual(
      `We have in total ${JobsDb.length}!`
    );

    // Find The filter jobs column
    expect(wrapper.find(`[data-testid="filter-title-desktop"]`).text()).toEqual(
      "Filter Jobs"
    );

// ERROR
   wrapper
      .find(`[data-testid="Marketing"]`)
      .simulate("change", {
        target: { checked: true },
      });
  });
```

Then the error :

```
 Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 7 found instead.
```

Any idea?
Where is the error?

Answer (score 0):

If just in case someone stumbles upon this problem, solution:

```
  wrapper
        .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
        .find("#id-checkbox");
```

Simulate click:

```
wrapper
            .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
            .find("#id-checkbox").simulate("change", {
      target: {
        checked: true,
... others if you need
              },
             });
```

Change state:

```
wrapper
            .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
            .find("#id-checkbox")
            .checked = true
```